# Copying a list of files from array

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to match filenames using the `-like` operator, and then copy the files that match with `Copy-Item` to a new directory:

Declare a list of files:

```
$files = "File1", "File2", "File3"
$sourceFolder = Get-ChildItem 'C:\source'
```

Match files by `Name` Property:

```
$filesToCopy = @()
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $filesToCopy += $sourceFolder | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "$file*"} | Select FullName
}
```

Finally copy files to destination:

```
foreach ($file in $filesToCopy) {
    Copy-Item $file -Destination 'C:\destination'
}
```

The last section is returning the error: `Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{FullName=C' does not exist.`

Output of `$filesToCopy`:

```
FullName
--------
C:\source\file1.txt
C:\source\file2.txt
C:\source\file3.txt
```

What am I doing wrong? FullName seems to be causing an issue.

Comment: Try `Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination 'C:\destination'`

Comment: @GarethLyons Thanks! It worked. Post an answer if you want - I will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$filesToCopy (and therefore $file) is an object with a property of FullName, so you need to reference the property to use it correctly:

```
foreach ($file in $filesToCopy) {
    Copy-Item $file.FullName -Destination 'C:\destination'
}
```